# Core Data Error executeFetchRequest:error:

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have been working with a Core Data database and it is set to load some data out of the database using the following code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AssignmentsInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSArray *dataReturn = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
dataSet = dataReturn;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestSubjects = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entitySubjects = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subjects" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequestSubjects setEntity:entitySubjects];
NSError *errorSubjects;
NSArray *subjectList = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestSubjects error:&errorSubjects];
```

But running this code returns the error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x16b1022 0x1842cd6 0xed3871 0x599a 0xe3a1e 0xe2fec 0x109f1d 0xf41cb 0x10adf1 0x10ae0d 0x10aea9 0x496f5 0x4973c 0x1a596 0x1b274 0x2a183 0x2ac38 0x1e634 0x159bef5 0x1685195 0x15e9ff2 0x15e88da 0x15e7d84 0x15e7c9b 0x1ac65 0x1c626 0x32ed 0x2385 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

I am not quite sure why this error is happening. I have triple checked and there are NO typos in the xcode model I have. The managedObjectContext is also perfectly working. Thanks for the help

Comment: You have an Entity called subjects? I ask because it seems like it would be more likely that you would have an Entity called "Subject" and that another Entity would have a relationship with "Subject" called "subjects".

Comment: Nah I have triple checked the names. It is definitely Subjects

Comment: Then you should do what Graver says. Use the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
1. Debug and see if `entitySubjects` is not `nil`
2. Try Product->Clean, Product->Build then try running, if it doesn't help
3. If you have added a new model version, you may have forgotten to set it as "Current Version" and if that's not the case
4. Your data may have got corrupted, try deleting it and run again
5. Last try is to recreate your model again, something might have gone wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your managedObjectContext is non `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would seem one or both of the calls to `[NSEntityDescription -entityForName:...]` are returning nil.

It could be that your data model was not correctly loaded or set on the managed object context.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the name of one of your attributes/entities and just tried deleting the app off the device its possible you could get this error. A good fix is to delete the app off of the device and to clean the project before building and running the app again. Just make sure to migrate your data after your app goes live rather than changing things the easy way.

The other possibility is that you might be trying to use a predicate on your request that is not set up the way you think, for example I had this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", UserId];
```

When my dataModel had that field set up as "objectId". Make sure they match. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after much aggravation, I found that the class that was assigned to the entity in the data model configuration had been removed. Typing in the name of the class removed the error.